# Techniques for solving a general system of First order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a general technique for solving Homogeneous system of first order differential equation 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dx_1}{dt} &=& \xi_1(x_1,...,x_k)\\
. \\
. \\
. \\
\frac{dx_k}{dt} &=& \xi_k(x_1,...,x_k)\\
\end{eqnarray*}
I have seen specific cases being dealt with, but want to know what are the most general techniques known.

Also, can one comment on number of independent solutions for this system ? I expect it should be $k-1$ but can't say why precisely.

Comment: Do you mean a **linear** homogeneous system?

Comment: No, those I could find in the books.

Comment: I don't need the whole proof if you can guide me to some texts on it.

Comment: So the $\xi_i$ are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree?  What do you mean by "number of independent solutions" in a nonlinear context?

Comment: If the equations can be anything, then there is no method. Note that the concept of "independent solutions" only works for linear equations. Once we move out of linear equations, we can't construct solutions this way.

Comment: The solutions for any $k \times k$ first-order system always form a manifold of dimension $k$, which you can parametrize by initial conditions.  Since the system is autonomous, you can take one of those dimensions to correspond to time translation.  Another dimension corresponds to scaling: if the $\xi_i$ are homogeneous of degree $d$, then $c y(c^{d-1} t)$ is a solution whenever $y(t)$ is a solution.

Comment: I understand that no technique is there to solve without any additional information about $\xi_i$. I will be happy to see that what non-linear systems have been tackled.  
Also, regarding independece of solutions, i realize that linear independence is meaningless here, and wanted to say functionally independent solutions. Defintion 1.9 http://www.math.umn.edu/~olver/sm_/g.pdf